# ERROR ReferenceError: config is not defined

Tags: angular

I am building a basic app with a login and registration page (in Angular 6). I followed a login/registration tutorial I found online, but for some reason when I attempt to login, I get

> ERROR ReferenceError: config is not defined.

As far as I can see, I believe there is an error with the authentication service which is, therefore, messing up the login component. I'm just not sure why the authentication service is giving me an issue.

See the code in the authentication service below.

```
   import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
   import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
   import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

 @Injectable()
 export class AuthenticationService {
   constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

   login(username: string, password: string) {
     return this.http.post<any>(`${config.apiUrl}/users/authenticate`, { 
     username: username, password: password })
       .pipe(map(user => {
    // login successful if there's a jwt token in the response
    if (user && user.token) {
      // store user details and jwt token in local storage to keep user logged in between page refreshes
      localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(user));
    }

    return user;
    }));
  }

   logout() {
     // remove user from local storage to log user out
    localStorage.removeItem('currentUser');
   }
 }
```

package.json

```
 {
      "name": "angular-login-and-registration",
      "version": "0.0.0",
      "scripts": {
        "ng": "ng",
        "start": "ng serve",
        "build": "ng build",
        "test": "ng test",
        "lint": "ng lint",
        "e2e": "ng e2e"
      },
      "private": true,
      "dependencies": {
        "@angular/animations": "^6.0.3",
        "@angular/common": "^6.0.3",
        "@angular/compiler": "^6.0.3",
        "@angular/core": "^6.0.3",
        "@angular/forms": "^6.0.3",
        "@angular/http": "^6.0.3",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.0.3",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.0.3",
        "@angular/router": "^6.0.3",
        "core-js": "^2.5.4",
        "rxjs": "^6.0.0",
        "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.6.6",
        "@angular/cli": "~6.0.7",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.0.3",
        "@angular/language-service": "^6.0.3",
        "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.6",
        "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
        "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
        "codelyzer": "~4.2.1",
        "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
        "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
        "karma": "~1.7.1",
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
        "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.0",
        "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
        "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
        "protractor": "~5.3.0",
        "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
        "tslint": "~5.9.1",
        "typescript": "~2.7.2",
        "webpack": "^4.15.1",
        "webpack-cli": "^3.0.8"
      },
      "description": "This project was generated with [Angular CLI](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli) version 6.0.7.",
      "main": "index.js",
      "keywords": [],
      "author": "",
      "license": "ISC"
    }
```

webpack.config.js

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/main.ts',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        use: ['ts-loader', 'angular2-template-loader'],
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.(html|css)$/,
        loader: 'raw-loader'
      },
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js']
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './src/index.html',
      filename: 'index.html',
      inject: 'body'
    }),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      // global app config object
      config: JSON.stringify({
        apiUrl: 'http://localhost:4000'
      })
    })
  ],
  optimization: {
    splitChunks: {
      chunks: 'all',
    },
    runtimeChunk: true
  },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true
  }
};
```

See the image of the error below.
[image]

Comment: From where comes config in your code? Where is it initialized?

Comment: You dont have a variable names `config`.

Comment: That's because you have to define a variable before you use it

Comment: As others have mentioned, `config` is likely an artifact of the tutorial you used. It would be helpful if you linked the tutorial, or told us how/where they defined `config` (my guess is it's imported from another file)

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies I'll look into initializing it. Here is the link to the tutorial. http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2018/05/16/angular-6-user-registration-and-login-example-tutorial

Comment: I see that he initialized config in the webpack. I'm just not sure how to access that file since I don't see it and there's not a standard angularcli command to create or access it... at least to my knowledge. Here is the link to the tutorial. http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2018/05/16/angular-6-user-registration-and-login-example-tutorial

Comment: @BrandonBrawley you don't have to figure out how to access it. The Webpack plugin makes `config` a global object. If you bundle the app with Webpack (after installing all the plugins), you probably won't see the error anymore. Try doing `npm i && npm run build && npm start`

Comment: Can you update your question with a copy of your Webpack config and your `package.json`?

Comment: @Atav32, I added the package.json to the code. I'm using Visual Studio and don't see the Webpack file anywhere in the solution. That's partly what's weird. Here's a link to what I did. https://webpack.js.org/guides/getting-started/ By this point, I'm thinking I installed the webpack incorrectly. Although from what I can see, I followed these instructions. Is there anything else that you need to see in order to better advise?

Comment: I was never able to successfully install the webpack.config instead I had the thought to download the solution from the tutorial and copy/paste the webpack.config from there to my solution. The original error is resolved but, I don't know the proper way to resolve this for anyone else having this problem. Additionally, I have a new error but, I'll research it to see if I can resolve it on my own. Thanks for all your help @Atav32!!!

Comment: Glad to help! What is the `ng` package and what does `ng build` do? Is that Angular's command line interface? Does it call webpack at any point? If you look at the `package.json` in the tutorial, you'll notice there are two scripts, `"build": "webpack --mode production",` and `"start": "webpack-dev-server --mode development --open"`. That lets you run `npm run build` and `npm run start`, which will use webpack to build and serve your app.

Comment: The ng package and ng build are Angular's CLI. I'm not sure how I would add the scripts you mentioned since those fields are already filled. I tried simply using a comma to separate but it didn't work.

Answer (score 7):

I encountered exactly the same error on exactly the same tutorial.

As the OP noted, the problem was that the TS (AuthorizationService.ts) was reading a Webpack variable (config) to pass a member variable (apiUrl) to an HTTP "POST":

```
 return this.http.post<any>(`${config.apiUrl}/users/authenticate`, { username, password })
```

If this were anything "serious", I would leverage the Angular environment files:

- [Becoming an Angular Environmentalist](https://blog.angularindepth.com/becoming-an-angular-environmentalist-45a48f7c20d8)

Since it was only a tutorial (a very *GOOD* tutorial, despite this little hiccough),I simply deleted "${config.apiUrl}" ... and everything "just worked".

FYI...

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Comment: Solved the same error trying on VueJS 3 using the tutorial from https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2018/07/14/vue-vuex-user-registration-and-login-tutorial-example . P.S. I don't have the webpack file after creating the Vuejs 3 app.

Answer (score 0):

Try editing your `package.json`'s scripts section

```
"scripts": {
  "build": "webpack --mode production",
  "start": "webpack-dev-server --mode development --open"
  "ng": "ng",
  "e2e": "ng e2e"
  "lint": "ng lint",
  "test": "ng test",
},
```

Then run `npm run build` followed by `npm start` (or `npm run build && npm start` in Unix)

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial you're referencing (https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2018/05/16/angular-6-user-registration-and-login-example-tutorial) uses Angular + Webpack, whereas it looks like your project uses the Angular CLI.

To migrate the Webpack version to an Angular CLI project you can:

1. Copy the webpack config variables to environment configs
2. Replace 'config.apiUrl' with 'environment.apiUrl' in services

I posted full instructions including a video showing the steps at https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2019/06/13/angular-7-tutorial-part-7-migrating-to-an-angular-cli-project#update-app-config

NOTE: deleting references to ${config.apiUrl} will also fix the error, but this will remove the ability to configure an apiUrl in one place.