# (webpack)/buildin/module.js Module build failed: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory,

Tags: angular, webpack

In an attempt to resolve another issue, which is still unresolved (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51199855/error-referenceerror-config-is-not-defined)), I attempted to add webpack 4.15.x to my code. Instead of the desired result, it immediately broke my code and gave me this error (webpack)/buildin/module.js Module build failed: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory and (webpack)/hot/emitter.js
Module build failed: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory. Actually, there was another similar error that was resolved when I uninstalled and reinstalled the node packages. Otherwise, I have no clue how to proceed. Please advise. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you on Windows? Googling "Module build failed: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory and (webpack)/hot/emitter.js" let to some interesting Github tickets

Comment: Yes, I'm on Windows. Yeah, when I searched the error, I didn't gain any further clarity.

Comment: Try these tricks, 1) https://github.com/darul75/web-react/issues/12#issuecomment-234809701, 2) https://github.com/darul75/web-react/issues/12#issuecomment-267388886, 3) https://github.com/darul75/web-react/issues/12#issuecomment-273600145

Comment: Just tried them. The first two didn't work. Not sure how to do the solution in link #3. More specifically, I'm not sure which file would need to be edited. Any idea?

Comment: please try to rebuild the project

Comment: @BrandonBrawley, 3) is referring to your webpack config file

Comment: yeah, try deleting `/node_modules` and `package-lock.json` then run `npm install`, then `npm run build` then `npm start`

Comment: OK, I deleted /node_modules and package-lock.json & ran the suggested commands. But, I'm getting this error... ERROR in src/app/_services/authentication.service.ts(10,35): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'config'. Which is one of the errors I was getting before. In fact, now the code won't compile. Any ideas @Atav32?

Comment: That's actually good! We've solved your Webpack installation error. Let's move the conversation to your other question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51199855/error-referenceerror-config-is-not-defined)

Comment: @Atav32 Thanks! I didn't even realize that meant the problem was solved. I really appreciate your help and patience!

Answer (score 7):

As mentioned in the comments:

Try deleting */node_modules* and *package-lock.json* then run

1. `npm install`
2. `npm run build`
3. `npm start`

Comment: this works but this is happening too frequently. Do you know how can we avoid this problem altogether?

Comment: @KaranJariwala can you explain what you mean by "happening too frequently"? What's causing the error for you?

Answer (score 0):

Got this error too after downloading some packages. I solved it by stopping the compile and compiling the project again.